# Error Handling Issue

Tags: loops, excel, error-handling, vba

With my function (within the greater code) I'd like to find a target column name. In another code I check to see if the column name is the cancel button (and I will adapt this accordingly as well)

But I want to make a for loop, 1 to 5 during which "If you enter an incorrect column name it asks you to resubmit. If you press Cancel it will exit function and exit sub after that (I'll fix that up myself).

```
Function FindText(Target As String)
Dim Value
Dim x

GoTo StartLoop

StartLoop:
For x = 1 To 5

With Rows(1)
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo FindDoesNotExist
.Find(what:=Target, after:=.Cells(1, 1)).Activate
End With
FindText = ActiveCell.Column
Exit Function

FindDoesNotExist:
Target = InputBox("Please Enter Correct Value(Row Name)")
GoTo StartLoop
Next x

FindText = 10000
End Function
```

Problem is I don't know how to clear the error, and so the "on error GoTo" doesn't work the second time. Could someone help either fix this code or make it better (In case there are tricks that I don't quite know yet?)

EDIT:

New Code is this:

```
Function FindText(Target As String)

 Dim x
 Dim found As Range

'StartLoop:
For x = 1 To 5

    Set found = Rows(1).Find(what:=Target, after:=.Cells(1, 1))

    If found Is Nothing Then
        Target = InputBox("Please Enter Correct Value(Row Name)")
    Else
        found.Activate
        FindText = ActiveCell.Column
        Exit Function
    End If

    Next x

    FindText = 10000
End Function
```

Upon meeting the after:=.Cells(1, 1)) area, it highlights Cells and gives: Error: invalid or unqualified reference. Any Ideas?

Comment: You would need to use `Resume StartLoop` rather than Goto. (or you could use `On Error Goto -1` I suppose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to stop the error happening in the first place. Something like this:

```
...
    Dim found As Range

StartLoop:
    For x = 1 To 5
        With Rows(1)     
            Set found = .Find(what:=Target, after:=.Cells(1, 1))
        End with

        If found Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Can't find " & Target)
        Else
            found.Activate
            FindText = ActiveCell.Column
            Exit Function
        End If
...
```

Hopefully that will be enough to help you fix your code.

Comment: It gives me Error, Invalid or Unqualified Reference.

I'm going to edit my original post to fit the code properly

Comment: @user3654055 fixed issue, please try edited version.

Comment: I am user3654055. Please read the stuff underneath the code because there is still a problem.

Comment: @user3654055 yes which I've fixed in my last edit... (copy and paste my new code from [With Rows(1)] ... to ... [End With])

Comment: Oh, ha. I thought you were saying that "user36... fixed my code". Let me try that again.

Comment: You did it! Thanks! I personally hate error handling because it's not getting to the root of the problem but I am a little new to VBA and didn't know that "Nothing" existed. That answers a lot of my error-checking problems, so thanks so much!

I would vote you up but apparently I need 15 reputation and don't have that yet. Sorry ForkandBeard

Comment: By the way ForkandBeard, you may know how to do this. Is there any way to immediately call the program to a halt instead of exiting function, exiting sub? Notice the 10000 there, I put that there so that if 10000 when I exit, the sub will exit as well, but I'd like this program to be more clean. Any Ideas?

Comment: but if I End it only ends the function/Sub that you're in, doesn't it? I'd like it to end the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a couple of things:

1. You probably want to guard against throwing an error inside a `With` statement. That can lead to some weird errors. So, I would join the `Rows(1)` with the `Find`; I would also qualify it with a sheet name, like this `Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(...)`
2. As a general rule, when you get into issues like this, try and split your code up into smaller functions. In this case, I was able to make a function that encapsulated the error handling so the issue was no longer an issue.
3. You'll want to avoid using `Activate` and `Select` whenever possible. In this case, they are not needed and the code is cleaner.

Like this:

```
Function FindText(Target As String)

    FindText = 1000 ' set default return value


    Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = getCellInRow1ByText(Target)

    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 5
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            FindText = foundCell.Column
            Exit Function
        End If
        Target = InputBox("Please Enter Correct Value(Row Name)")
        Set foundCell = getCellInRow1ByText(Target)
    Next x
End Function

Private Function getCellInRow1ByText(ByVal Target As String) As Range
    On Error GoTo Catch
    Set getCellInRow1ByText = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(what:=Target, after:=Sheet1.Rows(1).Cells(1, 1))
    Exit Function
Catch:
    Set getCellInRow1ByText = Nothing '' not really needed, but explains what's happening
End Function
```

The error handling probably isn't needed, but I've included it so that you can *learn the methodology.*

Btw, for a rigid answer to the original question, you could try adding

```
On Error GoTo 0
```